Second HDMI Display not detected (Ubuntu 24.04)
My second monitor is no longer being recognised. I have checked, and the hardware is working properly, so it is a software fault. I have tried changing my nvidia drivers and booting on a different kernel, but neither seems to work. I also recently updated the OS, but that made no difference. Could anyone offer any advice, please? Thanks in advance.
See further system information below:
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3
    Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: B450 I AORUS PRO WIFI v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Gigabyte model: B450 I AORUS PRO WIFI-CF v: x.x
    serial: <superuser required> BIOS: American Megatrends LLC. v: F61
    date: 07/13/2021
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 3 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1843 high: 3643 min/max: 400/4464 cores: 1: 400 2: 3589
    3: 3004 4: 400 5: 400 6: 3346 7: 400 8: 3643 9: 400 10: 400 11: 2997
    12: 3137 bogomips: 93428
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 Rev. A] vendor: ZOTAC driver: N/A
    arch: Turing pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:1f08
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: nouveau,vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting dri: swrast gpu: N/A display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1360x768 s-dpi: 84
  Monitor-1: default res: 1360x768 size: N/A
  API: EGL Message: No EGL data available.
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1 glx-v: 1.4 es-v: 3.2
    direct-render: yes renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)
    device-ID: ffffffff:ffffffff
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor: ZOTAC
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:10f9
  Device-2: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 0b:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1637
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 0b:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-40-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 5 Wireless-AC 9x6x [Thunder Peak] driver: iwlwifi
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 07:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:2526
  IF: wlp7s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: Gigabyte driver: igb
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: e000 bus-ID: 09:00.0
    chip-ID: 8086:1539
  IF: enp9s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter driver: btusb v: 0.8
    type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 3-10:2 chip-ID: 8087:0025
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.1
    lmp-v: 10 sub-v: 100
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 543.57 GiB (57.0%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Addlink model: M.2 PCIE G3x4 NVMe
    size: 953.87 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> temp: 35.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 937.33 GiB used: 543.57 GiB (58.0%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 4 KiB (0.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 54.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Info:
  Memory: total: 16 GiB available: 15.5 GiB used: 3.99 GiB (25.8%)
  Processes: 336 Power: uptime: 7m wakeups: 0 Init: systemd v: 255
    target: graphical (5) default: graphical
  Packages: 2744 pm: dpkg pkgs: 2678 pm: flatpak pkgs: 34 pm: snap pkgs: 32
    Compilers: gcc: 13.2.0 alt: 9/10/11/12 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.21
    running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.34


I posted an answer to this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527784/ubuntu-24-04-1-not-detecting-external-monitor-after-upgrade It might help you if it still doesn't work.
