Ubuntu 24.04.1 not detecting external monitor after upgrade
This system was upgraded from 22.04. I never had issues with external HDMI monitors before the upgrade. After the upgrade, the system would detect an external monitor when it was first plugged in but it would not detect when it was removed. This was annoying but I could handle it by manually deactivating the monitor in the Display settings. Today - for the first time - it happened that it did not even detect the monitor when it was first plugged in. This is annoying.
I found a lot written about this issue and the solution is "re-install the NVIDIA driver".
My system is a ThinkPad Gen 1 with AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 4750U with Radeon™ Graphics × 16. So obviously, the NVIDIA drivers can not be the issue here. I never had to install/re-install AMD drivers and I have no idea how to do it. The tutorials that I've found do not look trustworthy.
How would I go about debugging this issue? What is the official way to re-install AMD drivers on this system?
As a workaround: is there any way to manually re-start the driver or whatever is responsible for this? I can't reboot the system every day just for the display detection.
EDIT: I just found the worst possible workaround: sudo service gdm3 restart will restart the desktop session without fixing the issue. But it closes all windows which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid :-|

I had a similar issue.
I have a AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics so I think this solution would apply for you too.
I found a driver at AMD AMD driver
wget https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/6.2.3/ubuntu/noble/amdgpu-install_6.2.60203-1_all.deb

cd /user/bin
sudo ./amdgpu-install

After i installed it my external HDMI display works.
Hope it works for you too.

Thanks for sharing. After many updates to the Firmware and Ubuntu that were pushed during the last couple of weeks, it seems to work as expected now. I think I have upgraded a bit early. Ubuntu isn't that stable, even after the .1 release.
